# testing pyqt application with pytest

Tags: python, pyqt, pytest

I am testing a PyQt5 app using pytest and its pytest-qt addon.

I created a fixture to load my application class that I then use for all the test

I have two issues so far

1. The gui shows up and I don't want.
2. If I write more tests I will eventually get a segmentation fault as (I think) there are too many gui open.

any idea?
the documentation of pytest-qt is pretty basic and actually has a test that shows the GUI

a minimanl example is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QObject, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI(self)

    def initUI(self, MainWindow):
        # centralwidget
        MainWindow.resize(346, 193)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        # The Action to quit
        self.toolb_action_Exit = QAction(QIcon("exit.png"), "Exit", self)
        self.toolb_action_Exit.setShortcut("Ctrl+Q")
        self.toolb_action_Exit.triggered.connect(self.close)

        # The Button
        self.btn_prt = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_prt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 20, 89, 25))
        self.btn_prt.clicked.connect(lambda: self.doPrint())
        self.btn_quit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_quit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 20, 89, 25))
        self.btn_quit.clicked.connect(lambda: self.close())

        # The textEdit
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 321, 81))

        # Show the frame
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        # self.show()

    def doPrint(self):
        print("TEST doPrint")

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        # Ask a question before to quit.
        self.replyClosing = QMessageBox.question(
            self,
            "Message",
            "Are you sure to quit?",
            QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No,
            QMessageBox.No,
        )

        if self.replyClosing == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()


def main_GUI():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    imageViewer = Example()
    imageViewer.show()
    return app, imageViewer


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app, imageViewer = main_GUI()
    rc = app.exec_()
    print("App end is exit code {}".format(rc))
    sys.exit(rc)
```

and for the test:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import sys

import pytest
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtTest, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QObject, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from pytestqt.plugin import QtBot

GUI = __import__("GUI")


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def qtbot_session(qapp, request):
    print("  SETUP qtbot")
    result = QtBot(qapp)
    with capture_exceptions() as exceptions:
        yield result
    print("  TEARDOWN qtbot")


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def Viewer(request):
    print("  SETUP GUI")

    app, imageViewer = GUI.main_GUI()
    qtbotbis = QtBot(app)
    QtTest.QTest.qWait(0.5 * 1000)

    return  app, imageViewer, qtbotbis




def test_interface(Viewer):
    print("  beginning ")
    app, imageViewer, qtbot = Viewer

    assert imageViewer.textEdit.toPlainText() == ''
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: I do not observe the second error that you point out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to show the GUI then a possible solution is to use the `Qt::WA_DontShowOnScreen` flag, for this you must do the following:

- Remove `imageViewer.show()` in main_GUI.
- Add `imageViewer.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DontShowOnScreen, True)` and `imageViewer.show()` in Viewer fixture.

Comment: imageViewer.hide() worked as I could not find the WA_DontShowOnScreen attribute and it seems seg fault have stopped.

Comment: if I remove the show in main the GUI does not show when I run the GUI which is not what ones want

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to set the environment variable `QT_QPA_PLATFORM` to `"offscreen"` in your `pytest.ini`:

```ini
env = 
    D:QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen
```

If using `pyproject.toml`, that would look like this:

```ini
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
env = [
    "D:QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen"
]
```

I find the accepted solution doesn't fully work (e.g. your mouse is still moved, things clicked, and menubar menus still appear).

This solution does not appear to have that problem.

Comment: none of the two actually work

Comment: @bruvio From the shebang in your OP, I assume you're using Linux? In that case, you can try [pytest-xvfb](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-xvfb/). However, this works for me on Windows and using GitLab, so I don't know what issues you are facing. Even [`pytest-qt`'s `tox.ini`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-qt/blob/ab740a9bd0def6f705f5f5cd0d15cd03aee2df7c/tox.ini#L18) uses this, so it is battle-tested.

Comment: I use poetry and this is the pytest block [tool.pytest.ini_options]
addopts = '-s -v -p  no:warnings --cov=python  --cov-report=xml --cov-report=term --maxfail=1'
env = [
  "D:QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen",
]
filterwarnings = 'ignore::pytest.PytestConfigWarning'
log_cli = '1'
log_cli_date_format = '%H:%M:%S'
log_cli_format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s'
log_cli_level = 'INFO'
markers = [
  "skip_slow",
  "skip_in_ci",
  "run_in_ci",
  "skip_when_online",
]
qt_api = 'pyqt5'
testpaths = 'tests'

Comment: @bruvio I suggest going to the [pytest-qt repo](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-qt/issues) and ask for help by filing an issue with the request "Help Needed".

Comment: The following call before running tests solves the issue **export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen**

Comment: Yes, definitely: that is another way to do it. I’m sorry it wasn’t working for @bruvio